# vscode issue in .net6 project with system.net.http Library

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-6.0

I created a project and add System.net.Http nugget Package (dotnet add package).
But after that I'm still not able to use for example HttpClient class (class is not Found).

When I use Visual Studio Studio 2022 all Works.
when I take a look I see that Visual Studio 2022 use  :

**C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.5\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Http.dll**
As source.

How Can I had this reference properly to visual studio code ?

Comment: You need to install the runtime Core library on deploy machines that matches the version you used to build.  https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download?force_isolation=true

Comment: I Already Installed, but before asking here I updated my version to lastest stable one. same thing. I just added few seconds ago  my project to a solution and know it works. I don't know why :(.

Comment: If you change version of NET, the compiler dependencies do not recognize Net has changed.  Then you need to do clean build or delete all the intermediate obj files to force source code to get compiled with new version of net